# Java ScriptEngineManager and DOM

Tags: java, javascript, dom, scriptengine

Does anyone know any Java `ScriptEngine` that understand/include implicit `DOM` objects like `window`, `document`, `self` etc? I can't use `JavaFX WebEngine` as I am not developing JavaFX application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of solutions is using Envjs. Follow this [example](http://www.envjs.com/doc/guides#running-embed) how to embed into Java application. Now I can use `document.title`, `document.getElementById('embed_rhino_dojo_shell').innerHTML` etc.

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory;
import org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Global;
import org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main;
...
Context cx = ContextFactory.getGlobal().enterContext();
cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
cx.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_1_5);
Global global = Main.getGlobal();
global.init(cx);
Main.processSource(cx, "path/to/your/JSfile");
cx.evaluateString(...);
```

Comment: www.envjs.com is down. Refer to https://github.com/thatcher/env-js

Answer (score 1):

Not Perfectly answering your question

But We have used Qt's WebView which gives browser like functionality . It is same as JavaFX WebEngine . And PhoneGap also gives webview for mobile devices .

So please Clarify properly about in which situation you want to add Script Engine ?

see link for basic informations related to Qt
http://www.slideshare.net/QT-day/qt-webkit

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have that. DOM variables like 'window' and 'document' in a JVM don't make sense.

The Java ScriptEngine was made so you can 'script' the logic that you would normally perform in plain java.